# Layout Form data with Bootstrap 4 (for endfor / data in Django Template)

Tags: css, django, forms, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to ploy my formdata (some text and an image) onto the screen using bootstrap in a way that puts the blocks of data (text + image) next to each other instead of below each other. I played around with column sizes but I cannot get it to work. All containers are placed below each other on a big screen. On a small screen the layout is good, but on a big screen nothing flips over to the remaining columns

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<h1 class="my-4 text-center text-lg-left">Thumbnail Gallery</h1>

    {% block content %}
    {% for contexts in context %}
    <div class="col-lg-auto col-lg-auto col-6-auto">
    <h2>Title: {{ contexts.title }}</h2>
    <p>Category: {{ contexts.category }}</p></div>
    <p>Description: {{ contexts.description }}</p>
    <p>Price: {{ contexts.price }}</p>
    <p>Created: {{ contexts.created }}</p>
    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="{{contexts.document.url}}" width="20%" height="20%"/>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has excellent grid classes.
[Check it out here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

I'm not completely sure of what layout you are looking for but maybe this will get you in the right direction

```
<div class="row col-6">
    <div class="col-6 left">
        <h2>Title: {{ contexts.title }}</h2>
        <p>Category: {{ contexts.category }}</p></div>
        <p>Description: {{ contexts.description }}</p>
        <p>Price: {{ contexts.price }}</p>
        <p>Created: {{ contexts.created }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 right">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="{{contexts.document.url}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @chaggy that already looks better but it is still just giving all these blocks below each other, this time with the image on the right side of the text. What I'm looking for is to have either this (text left/image right) or text and image beneath each other, but then also as a pair next to each other. So for example text - image - new text new image next to eacht other or text/image pair - new text/image pair next to each other. Depending on the size of the screen. Small screen everything below each other, big screen as much as possible next to each other

Comment: if you can link to a visual example of what you are looking for maybe I can help

Comment: Something like this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OU9Y.png (picture placement (left/top) not that important. More like blocks of text/image next to each other (big screen/max columns available)

Comment: for that layout use the `col-md-4` class on 3 divs. Bootstrap grid is based on 12 so size 4 is a third. The 'md' part of the class is the breakpoint size

Comment: Where should I add there 3 divs?  Added col-md-4 in the second one but has the same behaviour, wich is placing all below each other in the first 4 columns. Not using the remaining 9.

Comment: Would the cycle tag be helpful here in any way?